# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0) : ReferenceError: Can't find variable TextInputEmail

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,Image,ImageBackground,
         TextInput,TouchableOpacity,AsyncStorage,
        ActivityIndicator,StatusBar,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack' ;
import {createAppContainer,createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import AppContainer from '../App'
import Forgot from '../Screens/Forgot' ;
 class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      TextInputEmail: '',
      TextInputPassword: '',
    };
  }

   CheckTextInput = async() =>
   {
     if (this.state.TextInputEmail != '')
         {
            if(this.state.TextInputPassword != '')
           {
              // if(userInfo.TextInputEmail === this.state.TextInputEmail &&
            // userInfo.TextInputPassword===this.state.TextInputPassword)

              fetch('http://104.197.28.169:3000/auth/login?', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  "email": TextInputEmail,
                  "password": TextInputPassword
                }),
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then(() => {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('drawernavi')
                    console.log('response object:',responseJson)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error(error);
                  throw error;
                });
              //  await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn','1');
              // this.props.navigation.navigate('drawernavi')
              //this.userLogin()
               // alert('Legged in')
              // this.userLogin();
          }
           else
            alert('Please Enter Password');
        } else
        alert('Please Enter Email & Password');
   }



  render(){
    return(

      <View>
       <ImageBackground style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}
        source={require('../images/login-screen.png')}>
        <View style={{flex:.8,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',marginTop:20}}>


        <View style={styles.imageView}>
<Image style={styles.logoImg}
source = {require('../images/core-logo.png')}
></Image>
</View>


          <TextInput style={{fontSize:15,borderWidth:1,borderRadius:20,paddingLeft:15,width:300,
          borderColor:'black',height:40,marginTop:40}} 
          keyboardType='email-address'
          maxLength={32}
          placeholder='Email' placeholderTextColor='#a8a8a8'
          onChangeText={TextInputEmail => this.setState({ TextInputEmail })}
          value= {this.state.TextInputEmail}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent">
          </TextInput>

          <TextInput style={{width:300,fontSize:15,borderWidth:1,borderRadius:20,paddingLeft:15,
          borderColor:'black',marginTop:20,height:40}}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          maxLength={14}

           placeholder='Password' placeholderTextColor='#a8a8a8'
           onChangeText={TextInputPassword => this.setState({ TextInputPassword })}
           value= {this.state.TextInputPassword}
           underlineColorAndroid="transparent">
          </TextInput>

          <TouchableOpacity
          style={{width:300,marginTop:35,paddingTop:10,paddingBottom:10,backgroundColor:'#2F6995',
            borderRadius:20,borderWidth: 1,borderColor: '#fff'}}

            onPress={this.CheckTextInput}
           underlayColor='#fff'>
          <Text style={{color:'#fff',textAlign:'center', paddingLeft : 10, paddingRight : 10,fontSize:17}}>LOGIN</Text>


     </TouchableOpacity>
         <View style={{alignItems:'center',marginTop:30}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('forgotstack')} >
         <Text style={{fontSize:12.5,color:'black',borderBottomWidth:1}}> Forgot Password ? </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
       </View>

        </ImageBackground>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

i am creating the functionality of login. i got this error while working on it.i am new to this. when i tried to login, the yellow warnings start appearing
i am fetching the data through a node.js api . so it is required that the input field name in api and react is same or it can be different or there is another way, please suggest correct my code if it is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     body: JSON.stringify({
                  "email": TextInputEmail,
                  "password": TextInputPassword
                }),
//Change it to
 body: JSON.stringify({
                  "email": this.state.TextInputEmail,
                  "password": this.state.TextInputPassword
                }),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `if(userInfo.TextInputEmail === this.state.TextInputEmail)` in this conditions `userInfo` is not defined so userInfo.TextInputEmail is not defined .

please check once